# Ember button not staying disabled

Tags: ember.js

I have an ember form where the button is supposed to be disabled for the creation of the object. The first two forms I did this on worked fine, this one is giving me issues. The button is disabled but then renables before the controller action is done.

**Goal:** Prevent double click on the Create button from creating a duplicate object
I attempted to do this by disabling the button after the first click

**View** (just the button piece)

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="submit-attribute"{{action 'submit' newAttribute}} {{bind-attr disabled="isProcessing"}}>Create</button>
```

**Controller** (in CoffeeScript)

```
App.SpecificationNewAttributeController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  isProcessing: false
  newAttribute: Ember.Object.create({
    name: ""
    datatype: ""
    group: ""
  })
  datatypes: ['number', 'range', 'list', 'boolean', 'date']

  actions:
    submit: (content) ->
      @set "isProcessing", true
      specification = controller.get('content')

      specId = specification.get('identifier')
      revision = specification.get('revision')
      specificationAttribute = @store.createRecord "SpecificationAttribute",
        name: content.name
        group: content.group
        datatype: content.datatype
        specification: specification
        specificationIdentifier: specId
        revision: revision

      specificationAttribute.save().then ((specificationAttribute) =>
        attributeId = specificationAttribute.get("id")

        specification.get('specificationAttributes').addObject specificationAttribute
        specification.save().then ((specification) =>
          specification.reload()

          groups = specification.get('specificationGroups')
          group = groups.where(display_name: content.group)[0]

          controller.transitionToRoute('specification', specification).then ->
            $.growl.notice title: "Specification", message: "New Attribute Added"
        )
        @set "isProcessing", false
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering this myself. It is a lame mistake but maybe it will help someone. I needed to move the `@set "isProcessing", false` into the inner `save().then` block:

```
  actions:
    submit: (content) ->
      @set "isProcessing", true
      controller = @controllerFor('specification')
      specification = controller.get('content')

      specId = specification.get('identifier')
      revision = specification.get('revision')
      specificationAttribute = @store.createRecord "SpecificationAttribute",
        name: content.name
        group: content.group
        datatype: content.datatype
        specification: specification
        specificationIdentifier: specId
        revision: revision

      specificationAttribute.save().then ((specificationAttribute) =>
        attributeId = specificationAttribute.get("id")

        specification.get('specificationAttributes').addObject specificationAttribute
        specification.save().then ((specification) =>
          specification.reload()

          groups = specification.get('specificationGroups')
          group = groups.where(display_name: content.group)[0]

          @set "isProcessing", false

          controller.transitionToRoute('specification', specification).then ->
            $.growl.notice title: "Specification", message: "New Attribute Added"
        )
      )
```

Comment: Hmmm... not so sure this is a useful question/answer. You might just want to delete it because really this has to do with promises and when they resolve, and this is an error specific to your code. You didn't really go into why your fix worked, either...